# Calculate $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\arctan(x^2+y^4) }{ \sqrt{x^2+y^2+1} - 1}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How can I calculate the limit of the following?
$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\arctan(x^2+y^4) }{ \sqrt{x^2+y^2+1} - 1} $$

I've tried using the sandwich rule, but after more than 2 hours, with no success.
Would my appreciate help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that

$$\frac{\arctan(x^2+y^4) }{ \sqrt{x^2+y^2+1} - 1}=\frac{\arctan(x^2+y^4) }{ x^2+y^4}\cdot\frac{x^2+y^4 }{ \sqrt{x^2+y^2+1} - 1}$$

with

$$\frac{\arctan(x^2+y^4) }{ x^2+y^4}\to 1$$

and using polar coordinates we obtain

$$\frac{x^2+y^4 }{ \sqrt{x^2+y^2+1} - 1}=r^2\frac{\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^4\theta }{ \sqrt{r^2+1} - 1}=r^2\frac{\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^4\theta }{ \sqrt{r^2+1} - 1}\frac{\sqrt{r^2+1} + 1 }{ \sqrt{r^2+1} + 1}=$$

$$= r^2\frac{\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^4\theta }{r^2}(\sqrt{r^2+1} + 1)=(\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^4\theta)(\sqrt{r^2+1} + 1)\to 2\cos^2 \theta$$

which is dependent by $\theta$.

---

To see that without polar coordinates let consider

- $x=y=t \to 0$ then

$$\frac{x^2+y^4 }{ \sqrt{x^2+y^2+1} - 1}=\frac{t^2+t^4 }{ \sqrt{2t^2+1} - 1}=\frac{t^2+t^4 }{ \sqrt{2t^2+1} - 1}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2t^2+1} + 1}{ \sqrt{2t^2+1} + 1}=$$

$$=\frac{t^2(1+t^2)(\sqrt{2t^2+1} + 1)}{ 2t^2}=\frac12(1+t^2)(\sqrt{2t^2+1}+1)\to 1$$

- $x=t \to 0$ and $y=0$ then

$$\frac{x^2+y^4 }{ \sqrt{x^2+y^2+1} - 1}=\frac{t^2 }{ \sqrt{t^2+1} - 1}=\frac{t^2 }{ \sqrt{t^2+1} - 1}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{t^2+1} + 1}{ \sqrt{t^2+1} + 1}=$$

$$=\frac{t^2(\sqrt{t^2+1} + 1)}{ t^2}=\sqrt{t^2+1}+1\to 2$$

Comment: Can you prove that without using polar coordinates?

Comment: @Dave Yes of course but why discard polar coordinates? this is a very fine method to study multivariable limits.

Comment: I prefer understanding another version which does not use polar coordinates, for better understanding with "basic" multivariable limits. Would much appreciate it if you could add another answer.

Comment: Just saw you added one. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why is arctan(x2+y4)/x2+y4→1 true?

Comment: @Dave Since $t=x^2+y^4 \to 0$ the limit is equal to $\frac{\arctan t}t \to 1$ which is a standard limit (or use l'Hospital for example).

Comment: Thank you! Much helpful.

Comment: @Dave You are welcome! Bye

Comment: Why in the second explanation did you split it to $x=y=t\longrightarrow0$ and $x=t\longrightarrow0$ $y=0$?

Comment: @Dave To prove that limit doesn't exist it suffices to show (at least) two different paths which lead to fiferent limits. This is the standard way we prove that a limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Of-course. I did not link that because I skipped the part that shows that the two paths' limit is 0. Thank you.